# Doubt in the transformation in R Shankar's Quantum Mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, reference-frames, coordinate-systems, linear-algebra

On page number $19$ of the book Principles of Quantum Mechanics by R. Sankar, The author describes a transformation, essentially a rotation of the axes by an angle of $\frac{\pi}{2}$ counterclockwise, about the $x$-axis. Then, as shown in the figure, he uses the old coordinate basis to describe the new transformed vector. Now my question is, how can a vector itself rotate in a transformation as the transformation essentially changes the coordinate basis and the coordinates of the vector and not the vector itself, also wwhy still are the old coordinate basis used?

(P.S. Have Uploaded the pics for reference[image: Image 1])

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Are you asking why he uses active rotation instead of passive rotation?

Comment: Yes...i want to confirm whether what he uses here is active or passive rotation. Also a few pages later he describes active and passive transformations in terms of operators and vectors. Are these active passive transformations same as the ones he describes later? If so...how?

Comment: He is using active rotation here. The rotation operator maps kets to other kets in such a way that it "looks like" a rotation on a normal vector space. The example rotates a vector in a space with basis {|1>,|2>,|3>} for an angle of $\pi/2$ about the |1> axis.

Comment: A passive transformation is a transformation of the coordinate system that lies over the space itself; an active one, is of the space itself.

Comment: Also, can anyone tell me that the active and passive transformations we have discussed here are or aren't same as rhe active and passive transformations discussed wrt transformation of vectors and operators?